# Sorting User control in a flow panel based on date in text box

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a program that pulls task from several different datasources populates some labels with information and puts the task due date into a textbox.  After all the task are added to the flow panel I want to sort the controls based on their due date.  After searching I found this.

```
Dim TheList =
    (
        From this In CA_Panel.Controls.OfType(Of Todo) _
        .Select(Function(item) _
                New With
                {
                    .Todo = item,
                    .date = CDate((From txt In item.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                                   Select txt.Text).FirstOrDefault())})
    ).OrderBy(Function(x) x.date)

    For index = 0 To TheList.Count - 1
        CA_Panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(
            TheList(index).Todo, index)
    Next
```

The problem is it keeps saying it can't convert string "" to date.  None of the text boxes are blank so I do not know where it is getting the blank string from any help is appreciated.  This is winforms vb.net

Comment: Is it running when there are no TextBoxes? Off the top of my head, wrap in `If CA_Panel.Controls.OfType(Of Todo).SelectMany(Function(c) c.Controls).OfType(Of TextBox)().Any() Then...`

Comment: I have tried both automatically after the user controls load and with a button.  The SelectMany had an overload.  I tried with just Selected and it went through each control but the if statement never resulted in true.

Comment: The `If` mirrors your situation: there are no TextBoxes returned. So you need to figure out how to get those TextBoxes. I was just thinking maybe this code was firing before they were added but it seems much more pervasive.

Comment: I don't know how to help you, I think you need to debug and inspect. For example what is inside `CA_Panel.Controls`? Are there any `Todo`? If so do any of them actually have a TextBox?

Comment: Wouldn't a much cleaner solution be to get your source data organised in such away that the controls are created and ordered correctly from the get go?

Comment: So after inspecting item its getting the "" from item.text which is odd to me.  As for organizing the data it comes from several different sources and would be difficult to get the formats close enough to populate a table to organize.

Answer (score 0):

So I was over thinking it.

```
 Dim TheList =
    (
        From this In CA_Panel.Controls.OfType(Of Todo) _
        .Select(Function(item) _
                New With
                {
                    .Todo = item,
                    .date = CDate(item.TextBox1.Text)})
    ).OrderBy(Function(x) x.date)

    For index = 0 To TheList.Count - 1
            CA_Panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(
                TheList(index).Todo, index)
        Next
```

Once I assigned .Todo = item I could then access the controls in the user control and just needed to convert to date and code works.